# Java - Catch an exception from async method

Tags: java, android, exception

I am developing a search by CEP (code address/zip code), and to make the search, I am using a third party api (postmon).

Every time I call the api with an invalid zip code, the app blows up and closes. I am trying unsuccessfully to catch the exception and returns it. Could help me understand where I'm going wrong? It is the type of this method?

```
        //Criar evento do botão
    btnBuscaCEP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //abre thread em background
            new HttpRequestTask().execute();
        }
    });

}

private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, DAOPostmon> {
    String charCepTrim = char_CEP.getText().toString().trim();
    final String url = "http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/"+charCepTrim;
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();


    @Override
    protected DAOPostmon doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            DAOPostmon DAOPostmon = restTemplate.getForObject(url, DAOPostmon.class);
            return DAOPostmon;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(DAOPostmon DAOPostmon) {

        //quando a tag Logradouro estiver disponiivel no retorno da api rest
        if (DAOPostmon.getLogradouro() == null) {

            TextView greetingEndereco = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputLogradouro);
            TextView greetingBairro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputBairro);
            TextView greetingCidade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputCidade);
            TextView greetingEstado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputEstado);
            TextView greetingCEP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputCEP);
            greetingEndereco.setText(DAOPostmon.getEndereco().toUpperCase());
            greetingCidade.setText(DAOPostmon.getCidade().toUpperCase());
            greetingBairro.setText(DAOPostmon.getBairro().toUpperCase());
            greetingEstado.setText(DAOPostmon.getEstado().toUpperCase());
            greetingCEP.setText(DAOPostmon.getCep());
            String endereco = char_Logradouro.getText().toString();
            BuscaGeolocalizacao localizacaoEnd = new BuscaGeolocalizacao();
            localizacaoEnd.getAddressFromLocation(endereco,
                    getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());

        } else {

            //senão, quando não tiver a tag logradouro, usar endereco

            TextView greetingLogradouro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputLogradouro);
            TextView greetingBairro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputBairro);
            TextView greetingCidade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputCidade);
            TextView greetingEstado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputEstado);
            TextView greetingCEP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputCEP);
            greetingLogradouro.setText(DAOPostmon.getLogradouro().toUpperCase());
            greetingCidade.setText(DAOPostmon.getCidade().toUpperCase());
            greetingBairro.setText(DAOPostmon.getBairro().toUpperCase());
            greetingEstado.setText(DAOPostmon.getEstado().toUpperCase());
            greetingCEP.setText(DAOPostmon.getCep());
            String endereco = char_Logradouro.getText().toString();
            BuscaGeolocalizacao localizacaoEnd = new BuscaGeolocalizacao();
            localizacaoEnd.getAddressFromLocation(endereco,
                    getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());

        }
    }
}
```

And the exception, when I call it with a wrong zipcode.

> 10-14 01:19:16.786 29926-29939/com.clubee.doggywalker W/art: Suspending all threads took: 31.097ms
>   10-14 01:19:19.767 29926-29939/com.clubee.doggywalker W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.260ms
>   10-14 01:19:19.770 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker W/RestTemplate: GET request for "http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/34575235" resulted in 404 (CEP 34575235 nao encontrado); invoking error handler
>   10-14 01:19:19.856 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker W/RestTemplate: GET request for "http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/34575235" resulted in 404 (CEP 34575235 nao encontrado); invoking error handler
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.clubee.doggywalker, PID: 29926
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 CEP 34575235 nao encontrado
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:76)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:524)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:481)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:237)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.clubee.doggywalker.DoggieWalker$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(DoggieWalker.java:150)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.clubee.doggywalker.DoggieWalker$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(DoggieWalker.java:137)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>   10-14 01:19:19.868 29926-29995/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>   10-14 01:19:20.059 29926-29926/com.clubee.doggywalker I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@224b3476 time:83894153

At the end of this post, I tried one more time, but now, using HttpClientErrorException...bad news.

Comment: looks like you are getting a 404 not found error

Answer (score 0):

First, please un-capitalize the names of the variables you are using: DAOPostmon is the name of the class, use dAOPostmon for your variable.

It seems like you have a couple of problems, you are returning the wrong type in your catch method. Just change

```
return e.printStackTrace();
```

to

```
e.printStackTrace();
return null;
```

and in your onPostExecute make your if-statement

```
if(DAOPostmon == null || DAOPostmon.getLogradouro() == null)
```

Comment: Thankyou, Hussain. after making the change, you can see the failure. But not only this catch would suffice for the error does not cause the application close?

Comment: Now, the error is java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.clubee.doggywalker.DAOPostmon.getEndereco()' on a null object reference

Comment: What line does it say the error is at? I don't see you calling DAOPostmon.getEndereco(), so it might be somewhere in the code that you did not include in your post.